What is the best container to store an {arbitrary jobject}'s data in C++?
I am writing an app that should use jobject's fields multiple times at a great speed. Since retrieving fields from jobjects is pretty slow, I want to do it once and then read and write fields of some C++ object or elements of a multitype array (if one can be created) or whatever that provides rapid data access (hereinafter - target container).
My code has two functions: first writes jobject fields into the target container, second reads the written data from it.
Target container should be capable of keeping variables of different type, and it's size must not be compile-time-defined (so struct is not suitable). The question is: what is the best container satisfying this conditions, if quality of it is defined by speed of reading (+converting types to proper ones) from it?
Right now, I use a vector<any> like below:
#include <vector>
#include <any>
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_runTask(JNIEnv*env,jclass,jobject o){
    vector<any>d;
    readData(d,/*some other arguments*/,o);
    do{
        //do something useful
    }while(predicate);
}

void readData(vector<any>*data/*some other arguments*/,jobject o){
    //fill the vector with jobject's fields' values
}

bool predicate(vector<any>*data){
    //determine the return value using vector contents
    return true;
}

vector<any> meets my conditions, BUT...

I am not sure that vector is the fastest container to read from.
any_cast<type>() is CHECKING the type before case, which means that it has imperfect performance.


@Eljay, to be honest, I did not measure performance, I've just read somewhere that "communicating" between C++ and Java (in both directions) is more expensive. I am going to take a measurement right now. I will update question and notify you as soon as I'm ready.

@Eljay, reading integer from std::vector<std::any> container is about 20 times faster than retrieving an int via JNI. That's significant.

By "I do not know the size of it" you mean you don't know what the value type of the hash map is? Or you don't know the amount of elements in the hash map?

@Wutz, I don't know both. I mean, I do not know what will be passed to function in runtime so I can not prepare a container just for one type or a container that has compile-time-predefined size.

@Wutz I don't know both -- You can get the size by using FindClass("Ljava/util/HashMap;") to get the Java class, then GetMethodID to get the method id of the size function.   Then from there, call CallIntMethod on the class and method ID.

@PaulMcKenzie, I know that I can easily get it's size, but some approaches may include using, for example, structs with limited amount of std::any fields, which are not suitable as it's fields' amount determined at compile-time, and I want to avoid such recommendations.

I guess the vector of any seems like the best solution given your current restrictions. But I'm wondering: if you don't know the value type at all, how are you even extracting the information to store in the any? If it can only be a limited number of different value types, you could use a std::variant<...> instead.

This is a peculiar access pattern. How often does the java side read and write its data? How often does the native side read/write?

@Botje, everything is done within C++ code, but it writes multiple env->CallObjectMethod "decrypted" (handy for usage) results to some storage (vector<any>, in my case)
at first, and then reads everything needed from that storage.

If everything is done on the native side why is the data stored on the java side in the first place? Consider serializing the java state into a byte buffer for C++ to read using eg flat buffers or protocol buffers.

@Botje, I've misexplained it. By "everything" I mean everything starting from the first JNI method call. To be more precise, the programm cycle divides into two stages: interaction with user via Java (and writing fields) and executing automatic task via C++. Since the first stage is completed, everything is done on the native side, so we can consider all jobjects are constant and data read from them is always relevant.

JAVA does not really like C++. The JNI is a bare minimum interoperability with C. Any proper C++ solution needs a wrapper around C API. There's no official C++ API, so the responsibility is on  the programmer. You can check various open-source projects and pick the right one. Otherwise you can note maintain the native part.

Then I reiterate: pass a flatbuffer to the native side

@Botje, why? I have succeded in reading from jobjects, I need to find the most suitable storage for multitype data.

@Red.Wave, Botje, you misinterprete my question. The goal is to find the multi-type  storage with maximum reading speed.

HashMap<String,Object> is a pretty sus type to be sending across a language boundary. Can you do better, e.g. HashMap<String, SomeDTO>? And if you can do that, could you instead serialise those SomeDTOs, and not have to do any JNI at all?

@Caleth, please read the updated question (in the end). Note, I do not have any problems with using jobject, I just need an object/array where I can put everything extracted from it. I even have one, but there should be a better option.

Can you at least tell us what kind of types you retrieve from Java? Maybe it all fits in a generic data structure like the ones used by JSON libraries. And then you might as well pass a JSON blob over the JNI boundary instead.

@Botje, this object won't be passed from one language into another, I will use the container only within C++. As for types, unfortunately, I can't predict what types I will use in the future, so any type should fit.

The "best reading speed" is to not do JNI

"I can't predict what types I will use in the future" why does this have to fit every type? it will be faster if it specialises to one task

I give up. You can have maximal flexibility or maximum speed but not both. Make up your mind.

@Caleth, let me try clairifying the situation one more time: I have a jobject, whose information is read once (this place doesn't require speed). That information should be stored in some container (hereinafter - target container). Data from target container will be read multiple times and this process should be as fast as we can achieve. The goal (and the help what I am asking about) is to determine, what kind of container to use as the target container. Note, reading from it will not use JNI, Java, and anything related to high-level languages.

The fastest thing will be a SomeSpecificType, tailored for exactly one task. Maybe make readData and predicate templates? Maybe if all the fields are the same type you could have std::vector<SomeOtherType>

@Caleth, I guess, decoding everything from one type will require more time than converting any to necessary type. Templates exclude the possibility of multitype storaging. One of exits that I see is using something like any, but without type-safety check upon type-casting (if such thing even exists).

Can you pin down the specific interface for what you want to do with this arbitrary data? class BaseTask { virtual foo frobnicate() = 0; /* etc */ }; and template<typename T> class Task<T> { foo frobnicate() override { /* do T specific stuff */ } };

Suppose I hand you a vector of any, without telling you what real types that any could store. What can you do with it?

As stated earlier, main problem is poor  API of JNI. It has a lot of repetetive string based code, written in very primitive fashion. One primary objective would be to overcome reference invalidations happening across calls to C++ module. You really need to use a 3rd party C++ wrapper for that; there's a tone of C++ fundumentals to learn before you can handle it on your own.

@n.m.couldbeanAI, I have two functions, both consist of switch expression, that gets a number based on the data should be stored in target container. They "know" what they do. All I need is to just transmit that container from one function to another. The second function will be executed many times, thus, I need a multitype container.

@Caleth, please read my comment above. I do not understand, why do I need such an interface.

If someone knows, how to improve the structure of my question to make it clear for someone who comes after us, please tell me. As I see, right now it's completely ununderstandable.

No, we understand your question. We just think that you have an XY problem

Not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but the first reaction is that each branch of your switch should be its own function, and the container should store that function together with the data to operate on, i.e. a bound std::function.

Any solution that allows arbitrary types to be stored in a container, and code interacting with that container magically knowing what to cast to, will be slower and buggier than code where there is a static type associated with each piece of data. The interface I wrote above was suggesting that you lift the polymorphism up from data to also include the operations that you perform on that data.

@Caleth, I am new in C++, and, from now on, I don't understand anything :(  I've tried my best to redescribe the problem in the question to focus on a very specific task. I would be glad if you try explaining approach with polymorphism one more time (but it is not necessary).

Rather than trying to use a container that can hold arbitrary data, we can wrap the data read and use in a polymorphic type.
As a sketch, you would rework Java_runTask to not have to deal with the data directly.
struct BaseTask
{
    virtual bool predicate() = 0;
    virtual Result process() = 0; // whatever "do something useful" does
};

std::unique_ptr<BaseTask> readData(JNIEnv* env, jclass c, jobject o)
{
    // based on c, construct a subclass of BaseTask, and read the data from o into it
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_runTask(JNIEnv*env,jclass,jobject o){
    auto task = readData(/*some other arguments*/,o);
    do{
        auto res = task->process();
        // do more processing
    } while(task->predicate());
}

You then need to have subclasses of BaseTask specific to your different kinds of data. One way of doing that is having a template subclass
template <typename T>
struct Task : public BaseTask
{
    T data;
    bool predicate() override;
    Result process() override; 
};

template <>
bool Task<Foo>::predicate()
{
    // data is a Foo here
}

template <>
bool Task<Bar>::predicate()
{
    // data is a Bar here
}

That's basically the same as defining
class FooTask : public BaseTask { /* all the members */ };
class BarTask : public BaseTask { /* all the members */ };


Oh, of course! Predicate can be dynamicly constructed! That is similar to the structure I have in Java (where I make new Consumer<> for each command) (which turned out to be too slow because of language's safety). Thanks a lot.
